# Can one omit "Es ist" from "Es ist A=B?" in German like one can in English?

Tags: german-to-english, mathematics

Take the following sentence:

> **Lemma.** Es ist A=B.

In English one could just write:

> **Lemma.** A=B.

Does this also work in German?

Comment: Are you looking for an English translation? I think you should ask on the English stack exchange instead, as this does not need German expertise. Or do you have a different question?

Comment: But this is about German text.

Comment: So you just want to know what it means? Generally, if there is something in German which you do not understand, then it can be on-topic here. If you understand the German text and want to know what the best way is to say it in English, then it is usually off-topic here.

Comment: @CarstenS We have a tag translation-de-to-en.

Comment: @infinitezero This would require that some user of English Stack exchange does understand German and has additionally a mathematical background. I think it is more likely that a user of German stack exchange has the required skills (German + English + mathematics).

Comment: @PaulFrost [Does my translation request belong here and if not, where and how shall I ask it?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1057/3237)

Comment: @Paul Frost, no it does not. [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/526457/english-term-corresponding-to-german-ausgangssperre) [are](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501922/english-translation-of-german-bureaucratic-term-weglegesache) [some](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284056/translation-of-the-german-term-steile-these) [examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583200/english-equivalent-of-the-german-suffix-weise). As for the mathematical background, the same is true for this stackexchange.

Comment: @C.F.G but you're asking for the translation of a German sentence.

Comment: @infinitezero: Not quite. My question is can one remove that words in German like English.

Comment: @C.F.G. could you [edit your question](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/70933/edit) then to make it clearer? Right now it states, and I quote: "What is the best translation of _Es ist A=B_" which is indisputably asking for the translation of a German sentence.

Comment: @infinitezero Read the first comment to [some](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284056/translation-of-the-german-term-steile-these): "
It would be better to post your question in German-related language site. I am sure there are some members who are fluent in German, but your quesiton doesnt' belong here, I am afraid. – user140086
Nov 1, 2015 at 6:00".

Comment: @PaulFrost Then keep on reading the second comment: "@Rathony: Neither version of this question would be on-topic on German Language, because it does not require expertise of the German but of the English language. If the asker were trying to understand the phrase’s German meaning, it would be on-topic there." From no other than Wrzlprmft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit "Es ist". The statement "A = B" has the same meaning. This is true both in German and in English.

Comment: Did you mean "Es ist" instead of "Es gilt"?

Comment: Oder: "Es sei A = B."

Comment: _Es sei A=B_ ist etwas völlig anderes als _es ist A=B_.

Comment: @RDBury Yes, I did not pay attention.  But "es gilt" and "es ist" have the same meaning in the present context.

Comment: One can simply write *A=B*, but if the remaining text uses full sentences, it does not look good.